# how can i call method in (ngModelChange) and apply a condition using angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript

here what i am trying to do is i want to disable a button

```
work= false;

    <button [disabled]="work"></button>
```

by default it is disabled now i want to make it active based on condition

say

```
(ngModelChange)="!Templatedata==name?'unDisable()':'disable()'"

unDisable(){
this.work= false;
}

disable(){
this.work = true;

}
```

the above condition is not working. although the same condition i applied for ngStyle & ngClass it works perfect but for ngmodelChange it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code does not working on `ngModelChange` you probably forgot to attach `[(ngModel)]` to the input.

Second, if you want to call function you can't pass function name in quotations:

```
(ngModelChange)="!Templatedata==name? unDisable(): disable()"
```